# Gratis Flutter package for a responsive, paged, data-driven grid

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, flutter

I am looking for a Flutter package that provides a grid widget.

My ideal would be something with the features of [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/); in fact, a Flutter wrapper for ag-grid would be great.

I want it to take its contents from data which I provide (and update with `setState()`; JSON would be fine, for example.

I want it to be responsive, to different screen sizes, and to auto-paginate when needed (virtual paging would be a bonus, in case of large data sets).

Other features:

- Column-sort
- click cell/column & handle in Dart code - onClick()
- formatting of rows/cells/columns
- anything else is a welcome bonus. The more full-featured the better, as I can't anticipate what I might want in future

I don't need two way data binding, as in Angualr(Js), but I won't sneeze at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Syncfusion's Flutter DataGrid](https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-datagrid) which has lot of features such as,

- [Column sorting](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/sorting)
- [Cell interactions callbacks](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/selection#cell-tap-callbacks)
- [Cell formatting](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/styles)
- [Paging](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/paging)

You can go through [Feature Tour](https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-datagrid) to know about all features and go through [UG](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/overview).

Comment: A great answer, which will help others who read this. Welcome aboard, and thanks for the answer. Alas, I cannot afford $995/year, so I will update the question to say so (my bad, sorry).

Comment: They provide free community license also. You can go through the below link,
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Comment: Fantastic. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks

Comment: "Who is eligible? 
Companies and individuals with less than $1 million USD in annual gross revenue and 5 or fewer developers" and "Can the products be used to build commercial applications? 
Yes"   This looks great. It is an excellent collection of components.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but the is a Dart wrapper for ag-grid [on GitHub](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/ag-grid)

Comment: [Pluto grid](https://pub.dev/packages/pluto_grid) also looks good